# How can I move compare product link in header | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.1, header, compare

How to move compare product link into header, Right now it is in top links. So to do so I've tried putting following line in my default.xml

```
<move element="compare-products-link" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

But it's not working ,another alternative was by putting following line

```
<move element="catalog.compare.sidebar" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

But it's putting whole div structure and I don't want it, I just want to have link. so any suggestions??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the element is `catalog.compare.link` as defined in `Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` :

```
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="catalog.compare.link" before="-"
               template="Magento_Catalog::product/compare/link.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProducts" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

So you can call the following:

```
<move element="catalog.compare.link" destination="header-wrapper" />
```

Comment: Hey @Raphael at Digital Pianism, You are the always first one to answer my question every time , Thanks ;) and yes by using this catalog.compare.link I've just moved it and I closely watch my question and found the answer in my question itself :D

Comment: @KaushalSuthar I'm glad your problem is solved. Thanks for the compliment =)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism How can I do this from a custom Magento 2.1.7 theme, instead of editing the default files?